# 'gem not found' error when installing rails 2.3.4 with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I try to install rails version 2.3.4 with rvm `rvm gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --version=2.3.4 rails`

but i get this error

```
'gem not found for ruby-1.8.6-p399' either does not exist or is not executable? :(
```

anyone know why? I have search google and found nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --version=2.3.4 rails` for the current ruby. You can see what's the current ruby with `rvm info`.

or if it's for a specific version of ruby you've installed with rvm that is not the current one, run `rvm 1.8.7 gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --version=2.3.4 rails`. In this example, it will install rails for ruby 1.8.7, although, the default in my computer is ruby 1.9.2.